# Provide correct Android Activity stack navigation

Tags: android, android-activity, android-navigation

I'm writing a simple android application, it has only 3 activities but I'm having troubles providing the correct "up/back" navigation.

The first activity is a ListActivity, it has a list of clickable items and a NewItemFAB.

- A click on one of the Items opens the DetailActivity.
- A click on the FAB opens the New/Edit Activity.

From the DetailActivity you can only go up to the ListActivity or tap on the EditFAB to open the New/Edit Activity to edit that Item.

From the New/Edit Activity I want to:

- If it was a new item from the ListActivity:

  - If the Item is saved go to the DetailActivity not the ListActivity that called it, and after that going back from the DetailActivity should bring to the ListActivity and not the edit one.
  - If the user go back or discard the Item it should go back to the ListActivity
- If it was a Item being edited from the DetailActivity:

  - Both going back or saving the changes should display the DetailActivity and going back from there should bring again to the ListActivity.

I've tried using navigateUpTo, finish(), Flags, different `LaunchMode` and even the `noHistory = true`, the New/Edit Activity has the DetailActivity as parent, while the DetailActivity has the ListActivity.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: There are many ways to do this. You definitely don't need any special launch modes or `noHistory`. In general, calling `finish()` (or simply pressing the BACK key) will close the current `Activity` and bring you back to the previous one. That is mostly what you want. Please be clear about the other cases and maybe we can help with those.

Comment: I'm asking because pressing the back key, wasn't showing the right Activity. I tried harder with the finish() and looks like it worked. I hope this is the best way though, i'm not completely sure about that.

Comment: You should post some code. I don't really understand your problem.